# Reverse Proxy with redirect to Sub-URL + URL Parameter

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting, webserver, reverse-proxy

I have an IIS for the site web.test.com on Port 80 and 443 that is used as reverse proxy for another web-server configured on the same server on port 8090. So I'm using the IIS rewrite module and ARR module with the following rule.

```
<rule name="RULE1" enabled="true">
     <match url="(.*)" />
     <conditions>
     <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="web.test.com" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8090/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

I would like to add a redirect (or extended rewrite) that if someone goes directly to web.test.com , the URL is rewritten/redirected to web.test.com/foo/index.html?bar (which technically is localhost:8090/foo/index.html?bar) - so it should go to a file in a sub-url and add a URL parameter to the url.

Does anyone know how to do this. I found a lot of instructions on how to redirect, but never in combination with reverse proxy.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a redirect rule then Move up the redirect rule ahead your Reverse proxy rule.

```
            <rule name="Redirect Rule" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^(/)?$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="/foo/index.html?bar" redirectType="Temporary" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="RULE1" enabled="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domain.com" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8090/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
```

The order should looks like this:
[image]